# How to download files larger than 4 GB on Android external SD card

Tags: external-sd

So I wanted to download a file that is 7GB to my memory card on my Android phone (Lollipop). What should I do? I have heard that I should format my SD card to exfat, but I don't know how to do that. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

**Formatting your sd card will erase all data stored on it!**

You can format your sd card easily on android. Go to `settings` -> `storage` -> `sd card`. Now you should have a `format` menu option.

You can also format the sd card with most desktop os' like Windows or macOS. In Windows you can select `format` in the context menu of the connected sd card.

Comment: Just a record, sometimes FAT32 is the default for a phone, making formatting on-phone useless.